# I'm trying to run this program but I keep getting this error

Tags: r

```
 # Cycle through files 
for (i in 1:length(filelist)){
  currentjsonimport = fromJSON(file = filelist[i])
  tmp = NULL
  
for(j in 1:length(currentjsonimport$voiceMemoData)){
    
    ## import voice memo data
    tmp = t(currentjsonimport$voiceMemoData[[j]][[1]])
    matrixtmp <- as.matrix(tmp)
    coords <- rbind(coords, matrixtmp)
}
}
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fromJSON’ for signature ‘"missing", "missing"’
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the package installed.
Try running this first -

```
install.packages("rjson")
library(rjson)
```

Hopefully this works!